# iOS Alternative option to retrieve the user location when GPS is turned off or not available

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am developing a news application that should retrieve the user location in order to send the corresponding news related to his position.
Everything will work perfectly if the user has already granted the location permission. My issue is occurring when the user deny the location permission and I can't retrieve his location and the CLLocationManager DidFailWithError method is being called.

The location services framework, as I understand it, uses a 3-stage algorithm to determine user location.  It attempts to fix location via: GPS, Wi-Fi, network, in order of preference.

I need an alternative option to retrieve the user location when GPS is turned off or not available. Can’t the app use a secondary (less accurate lat/lon) retrieved from the cached network/Wi-Fi lat/lon estimate?(or any other method)

Comment: If the user has denied you permission to access their location, you shouldn't access their location; perhaps you could ask them to supply a location such as a city.  If the user has granted permission but GPS isn't available then iOS will automatically provide the best location it can determine based on cell towers & wifi.

Comment: @Paulw11 What if the location was turned off by the user .. how to get the location by a second method?

Comment: If the user has turned off location, then they don't want you to have their location by any method.

Comment: @Paulw11 it is an enterprise app(Will not be uploaded to the store) and it is the requirement. So it should be done like requested. I know it is a privacy issue, but it is the enterprise requirement.

Comment: Well you can try ip based location as suggested in the answer below but none of the iOS Core Locstion methods will be available if the user has denied location access

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about user current city in order to send him news then you can achieve that. Try to request news from your server api as you are doing right now, on server side check if you don't get any latitude longitude from request params then you use user ip address to get user city info. Search for some services which gives you location info based on user IP address. Hope that helps